# How do I get dynamic (sections appear as they're being chosen) forms on "dumb" WAP phones (no Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, forms, dhtml, mobile-phones, wap

my site page's goal is to get information from a fairly complex (but concise) form.  Ease of use is a big deal for me so when I tested the form on a WAP emulator, I was disappointed to see nothing happen when I clicked on radio buttons that successfully display the correct portion of the form on normal browsers, including the iPhone's.  I've realized that this is because the code in the page is javascript and most dumb WAP phones don't support it.  When I implement javascript, it's so that form options below a radio button don't show up until they are selected, and I know what you're thinking - "just make default forms options pop up" - but I couldn't figure out how to do that without ruining the whole appearing/disappearing act.

I suppose I could ask the browser if it supports javascript and redirect it to the javascript-enabled page if it does, or one without dynamic stuff if it doesn't... I wish there was a better option but how would I do that?  BIG thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could either use <noscript> to display the whole form on "dumb phones" or you could make some "config wizard"-like thing, like showing the radiobuttons on one page, submit it, and then (using php/ASP/whatever) send only the fields that depend on the previously checked options.